# Using Point3d but need to access x,y,z coordinates on their own

Tags: java

So I have x, y and z coordinates formed from calculations

```
pointX = (1000*curve.x) +(1000*line.x);
pointY = (1000*curve.y) + (1000*line.y);
pointZ = j * 2;
```

I am then using Point3d to allow these coordinates to be specific for a point

```
Point3d points = new Point3d(pointX, pointY, pointZ);
```

I have then set up an array of these points

```
Array[i][k] = point;
```

The array is defined previously and the above is all part of a loop. All of the coding works fine. I am now creating an STL file of these points and so have created the vertices for the triangles.

```
for(int z=0;z<number.length-1; z++){

Point3d vertice1 = pointArray[f][g] ;
Point3d vertice2 = pointArray[f][g+1] ;
Point3d vertice3 = pointArray[f+1][g] ;
```

I then print these vertices in my STL code.

However, due to using Point3d the vertices are layed out as such: (x,y,z) and for the STL file to work they need to be as such : x y z.

So is there a method of 'getting' the x, y  and z coordinates at the point where I am creating vertice1, vertice2 and vertice3 or (a better option!) is there a way I can eliminate the brackets and commas in the Point3d values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Add and Use:

```
public String format(final Point3d point){
    return String.format("%s %s %s", point.x, point.y, point.z);
}
```